# Why isnt mouseleave event working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a JSFiddle that works perfectly

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3g6s/)

I want the div to change colors when hovered over and then back to its original when the mouse moves out. My fiddle works perfectly but when I run it locally, it only changes to grey and not back to its original color.

Jquery

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Logo Replacement
        window.onresize = function (event) {
            var screenWidth = $(window).width();
            if ((screenWidth) < 969 && (screenWidth) > 769) {
                $("#logoHolder img").attr("src", "images/payday_ira_logo_stacked_web.png")
            }
            else {
                $("#logoHolder img").attr("src", "images/payday_logo_long_web.png")
            }
        }
        //Button Color Change
        $("#employerButton").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#employerButton").css({ "background-color": "grey" });
        });

        $("#employerButton").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#employerButton").css({ "background-color": "#6EBE44;" })
        });
    });


</script>
```

CSS

```
#employerButton{
    background-color:#6EBE44;
    height:35px;

    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="d3-d6 m1" id="employerButton">
    Employer
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing this with jQuery instead of just CSS? Add CSS for `#employerButton:hover`.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors. You probably have a typo in the the local version, which isn't in the fiddle.

Comment: If your fiddle works perfectly, but testing locally doesn't, the error is probably not related to the posted code. Open your console and check for errors. @Barmar +1 !!

Comment: Inside your mouseleave remove the semi-colon at the end of the color and add it to the end of the line.

Comment: @Barmar is right - this question is an example of XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you can try:
1. Copy the fiddle code to your local save. If the fiddle works perfectly, it should locally as well - so make sure you have identical code.
2. Try using the `mouseout` event instead. There is little difference but your browser may interpret it differently.
3. There are a few syntax errors in your code as well. For example, there are a couple of semicolons in the wrong place which could affect execution - check updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3g6s/1/).

N.B: If you're using jQuery, you can use it for `window.onresize` as well - just a hint.

```
$(window).resize(function() { ... });
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: In principle, I would also agree with Barmar's comments - use CSS instead if at all possible. Around 10% of Internet users are on legacy browsers (no JS support) or have JS disabled - so this change won't work for 10% of your users. Again, updated fiddle (with CSS this time) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3g6s/2/).

Comment: Your updated fiddle worked for me. However, after reading the comments, I will use the CSS solution instead. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use mouseout function instead of mouseleave, for example:

```
$("#employerButton").mouseout(function(){
$("#employerButton").css({"background-color" : "#6EBE44"});
});
```

and it works like a charm.

Maybe you should use CSS for the following code:

```
#employerbutton:hover{
   background-color : #6EBE44;
}
```